# Configuring Tomcat 7 for Mutual Authentication using a Tomcat Connector or custom Socket Factory

Tags: tomcat, soap-client, connector, mutual-authentication

Is it's possible to configure Tomcat to carry out Mutual Authentication using a connector or custom socket factory?

My scenario involves a Tomcat web application that includes a SOAP client call to a DataPower server.

Mutual Authentication is needed on DataPower but the web app client does not have any SSL code in it.

I don't have the flexibility to change the SOAP web app client and am looking at alternatives.

I could write a "forward proxy" web service to act as the MA client between Tomcat and DataPower but I am hoping for a "configuration" solution in Tomcat rather than writing more code.

I have searched quite a lot and couldn't find anything that quite hit the mark, so I am hoping someone else has come across this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I googled this out: http://techannotation.wordpress.com/2012/06/22/tomcat-mutual-authentication-over-ssl/. Like your donkey picture.

Comment: @mwarren, thanks.  I have the Tomcat server set up ok and DataPower can talk to it via HTTPS and MA.  I didn't need to set the user credentials and MA/HTTPS works fine with just an SSL connector configured with a keystore & truststore.  The problem I am having is with the Tomcat client app.  If you think of the sequence as Tomcat Client App -> DataPower -> Tomcat Server, the Tomcat Client App has no Java code written to set up keystores/truststores.  I am trying to find out if I can configure a Tomcat Client connector to do HTTPS/MA on behalf of the client app.  It's a tough one.